# SSIS or TSQL for SQL/MySQL table comparrison

Tags: t-sql, ssis

I am new to SSIS and am after some assistance in creating an SSIS package to do a specific task.  My data is stored remotely within a MySQL Database and this is downloaded to a SQL Server 2014 Database.  What I want to do is the following, create a package where I can enter 2 dates that can be compared against the create date/date modified per record on a number of tables to give me a snap shot and compare the MySQL Data to the SQL Data so that I can see if there are any rows that are missing from my local SQL Database or if any need to be updated.  Some tables have no dates so I just want to see a record count on what is missing if anything between the 2.  If this is better achieved through TSQL I am happy to hear about other suggestions or sites to look at where things have been done similar.

In relation to your query Tab :
"Hi Tab,  What happens at the moment is our master data is stored in a MySQL Database,  the data was then downloaded to a SQL Server Database as a one off.  What happens at the moment is I have a SSIS package that uses the MAX ID which can be found on most of the tables to work out which records are new and just downloads them or updates them. What I want to do is run separate checks on the tables to make sure that during the download nothing has been missed and everything is within sync.  In an ideal world I would like to pass in to a SSIS package or tsql stored procedure a date range, shall we say calender week, this would then check for any differences between the remote MySQL database tables and the local SQL tables.  It does not currently have to do anything but identify issues, correcting them may come later or changes would need to be made to the existing sync package.  Hope his makes more sense."

Thanks P

Comment: The MySQL data is "downloaded to a SQL Server", so you only need to compare two tables on the same SQL Server?  Is this correct?

Comment: In order to ensure things are in sync you need a key that you can compare between systems. Do you have that? I suggest you forget about interactively entering dates and instead compare data in the entire tables. It's more useful to know whether the entire table is consistent rather than just a piece of it. Besides SSIS is not really built for interactive use. Instead you would normally load these dates from a table or from an environment.

Comment: Hi Nick,  thanks for the comment in answer to your questions yes there is a key that can be compared between the tables.  The reason that I wanted to be able to perhaps enter dates is there could be legitimate differences in data downloaded with in the last 24/48 hours so I wanted to exclude this data from the check.  In the ideal world I would like to use this package against multiple databases, they have more or less the same tables but are not complete copies.

Comment: For a record level comparison your two options are: 1. Use SSIS to compare 'on the fly' as suggested by @iamdave; 2. Copy all the MySQL data locally and run a query to compare. If you just want to compare record counts that's much easier. But you should really focus on a reliable replication method that doesn't need to be checked in this way

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for the reply.  I agree the focus should be on a more reliable replication method but unfortunately at the moment I am not being given the time to properly look through what is currently in place and they are adamant that all is fine but want me to clarify it with a regular dip check of data every week, though at some point in the near future I will look at rewriting the current replication pack.  For now I will adopt one of iamdave's suggestions. thanks PD

Comment: Ah I totally understand :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you need to implement a Type 1 Slowly Changing Dimension type data flow in SSIS.  There are a number of ways to do this, including a built in transformation aptly called the `Slowly Changing Dimension` transformation.  Whilst this is easy to set up, it is a pain to maintain and it runs horrendously slowly.

There are numerous ways to set this up using other transformations or even SQL `merge` statements which are detailed here: https://bennyaustin.wordpress.com/2010/05/29/alternatives-to-ssis-scd-wizard-component/

I would recommend that you use `Lookup` transformations as they perform better than the `Slowly Changing Dimension` transformation but offer better diagnostics and error handling than the better performing SQL `merge` statement.

Before you do this you will need to add a `Checksum` or `Hashbytes` column to your SQL data for ease of comparison with the incoming MySQL data.

In short, calculate some sort of repeatable checksum as the data is downloaded into your SQL Server, then use this in an SSIS `Lookup`, matching on the row key, to check for changes.  Where the checksum value is different for the same row it needs updating and where there is no matching row key in your SQL Data you need to insert the new row.